# How to mock the Controller of an AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs

Given a directive that has an external controller:

```
.directive('d1', function () {
  return {
    controller: 'd1controller',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, $controller) {

      $controller.doStuff();

    }
  };
});
```

**How do I mock the `d1controller` controller in the `d1` directive's unit tests?**

---

My attempts:

I tried with `$provide` as when mocking a service:

```
  beforeEach(module('app', function ($provide) {
    ctrlMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ctrlMock', ['doStuff']);
    $provide.value('d1controller', ctrlMock );
  }));
```

And I also tried with `$controllerProvider`

```
  beforeEach(module('app', function ($controllerProvider) {
    ctrlMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('ctrlMock', ['doStuff']);
    $controllerProvider.register('d1controller', ctrlMock);
  }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the OP. It turns out that using `$controllerProvider` works. You have to pass it a constructor; not an instance.

```
beforeEach(module('app', function ($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.register('d1controller', function Mock(){
    this.doStuff = function(){};
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had decent luck creating a mock module, that contains all of my mocked services/controllers and then including that mock module after my app module.  It will essentially override all of the services/controllers you have in your mock module.

Create your mock module, and your controller to mock in that module.

```
appMock = angular.module('appMock', []);

appMock.controller('ControllerToMockCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

In your test.

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('app');
  module('appMock');
});
```

This blog is a good example of this strategy.  http://southdesign.de/blog/mock-angular-js-modules-for-test-di.html#using-the-mock

Comment: Nice trick. I created a `mockDirectiveController` helper to hide the implementation details. See https://gist.github.com/sylvain-hamel/9122684