# Using jasmine.spyOn to verify ng-click behavior

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I'm trying to verify using Jasmine that an element with the ng-click directive has the correct behavior when clicked.

### view.html

```
<div ng-controller="FooController as $ctrl">
    <a id="fooLink" ng-click="$ctrl.fooFunction()">
         Call fooFunction!
    </a>
</div>
```

### foo.tests.ts

```
describe("the view", () => {
        let viewElement: JQuery;
        let ctrl: FooController;

        beforeEach(() => {
            ctrl = $controller('FooController', { '$scope': $scope });

            let viewHtml = $.ajax('view.html', { async: false }).responseText;

            viewElement = $(viewHtml);
            $compile(viewElement)(ctrl.$scope);
        });

        it("should call fooFunction() when clicked", () => {
            spyOn(ctrl, "fooFunction");
            link = viewElement.find("#fooLink");
            link.click();
            expect(ctrl.fooFunction).toHaveBeenCalled(); //FAILS :(
        }
    }
```

The test fails with `Expected spy fooFunction to have been called.`.  I've verified through debugging and other tests that `fooFunction` *is* called on click, so the problem seems to be that `$scope.fooFunction` and `$ctrl.fooFunction` aren't the same function. Also, debugging has shown that `fooFunction` executes even though it should have been overridden by the spy. How can I write this test such that Jasmine properly tracks calls made to controller functions from ng-click expressions?

**UPDATE**: I attempted to use `$controllerProvider` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917452/how-to-mock-the-controller-of-an-angularjs-directive)) to provide a spy object to the view, with the same results.  Debugging shows that the controller does in fact have a spy on the desired function name; it just doesn't track the call made by the ng-click.